# Power Set, Bijection Function, Equivalence Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Let $S$ be a set and $P(S)$ the power set of $S$. For sets $A,B⊆P(S)$, we say that $A \sim  B$ if there exists a bijective function $f: A \rightarrow B$. Show that $\sim $ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: I know the following:
The identity function gives you A~A 
If f is a bijections from A to B so that A~B, then g = f^-1 exists, is a bijection, and gives you B~A. 
Composition of bijections is a bijection and gives you transitivity.

Comment: Seems that you have the answer. What are you asking for, then?

Comment: I'm confused as to where the symmetry comes in to play since an equivalence relation is symmetric, reflexive, and transitive

Comment: or is it just because f is a bijection where f: A->B?

Comment: Symmetry is exactly taking $f^{-1}$.

Comment: ok thanks alot!

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773465/equivalence-relations-and-power-sets