# Equivalence relations and power sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the class of all sets and define the relation $R$ on $\mathcal{A}$ as: $A\space R\space B$ iff there is a bijective function $f:A \to B$. Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{A}$.

I know I need to prove bijection by proving injection and surjection, but I don't even know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- There exists a bijection $A\to A\forall A\in\mathcal{A}$.
- If $A r B$, then $BrA$ since bijections have inverses.
- If $ArB,BrC$, then there exists a composition of bijections $A\to C$, which is in turn a bijection.

Now use the definition of equivalence relation.

Comment: So, I just need to prove reflexive, transitive, and symmetric?

Comment: @user3258394 yes, that's right.